# Find whether the business is working pass midnight?

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6

for instance if a business has the working hours like so:

```
const hours = {
 open: '21:00', // -> same day
 close: '5:00'  // -> next day
}
```

what is a reliable way to understand that this business works past midnight?

```js
let open = 21, close = 5;

open > close ? console.log('pass midnight!') : console.log('not pass midnight!')
```

this seems a little fishy to me

Comment: Why does that seem fishy? If the business appears to close before it opens (`close < open`), then it's probably a wrap-around to the next day… Or a business catering to time travellers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pseudo-algorithm, if `open > close` then the business is open at midnight. Of course you need to translate those times to a type you can correctly compare, like `Number`.

Alternatively if you can manipulate the way the hours are provided, you could add 24 to the close hours when it is the next day, which might help in certain situations, like calculating the number of open hours.

Comment: Thanks, and what would be the way to check if current hour is passed the midnight time? `current > open` ?

Comment: Isn't current time always past midnight? :/

Comment: @JasonBrill as Sunny points out that does not really make sense. Maybe you want to check if the current time is both before the opening time and the closing time : if `current < close < open` (the business is open during nights) then it means you're between midnight and the close time, and if `current < open < close` (the business is open during days) it means you're between midnight and the opening time.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta—and simultaneously always before midnight…

Comment: @RobG - Well, Chicken or Egg? :)

Comment: @SunnyRGupta—clearly the egg. Or maybe the chicken. Then again… ;-)